# How can I allow the user to filter Wordpress Custom Post Type by a postal code

Tags: wordpress, filter, content-management-system, custom-post-type, meta-key

I have a custom post type called 'partners', each partner has a custom field called 'postal_code'. I would like to add an input field in the front end so that users can filter the partners by entering a (Swiss) four diget postal code (it's only numbers). Resulting it for example showing 10 partners nearest to them based on the numerical postal code.

Any help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args= array(
   'post_type' => 'partners',
   'meta_key' => 'custom_field_name',
   'meta_value' => 'ND',
   'paged' => $paged
);

query_posts($args);
```

or use WP_Query if You like it more.

More info:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters